# exception trace does not show line number for private method after use ProGuard

Tags: java, android, exception, proguard

for example, the followng error message shows that NullPointerException thrown from line number 435 in GameController.java:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.fuu.mahjong.game.GameController.boolean showHint(boolean)(GameController.java:435)
at com.fuu.mahjong.game.GameViewActivity.boolean onTouch(android.view.View,android.view.MotionEvent)(GameViewAct
ivity.java:1552)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7122)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
...
```

where line number 435 in GameController.java is

```
clearCurrentSelections();
```

clearCurrentSelections() is a private method in GameController, the error message does not show trace information inside clearCurrentSelections(), if I change clearCurrentSelections() to public, then the error message shows that which line in clearCurrentSelections() cause the NullPointerException.

Is there any way to show the trace information inside a private method after use ProGuard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ProGuard's optimization step has probably inlined the method. The virtual machine then produces fewer lines in the stack trace. If you want to avoid this, you can disable method inlining:

```
-optimizations !method/inlining/*
```

On the Dalvik virtual machine, method inlining improves the performance though.

Whether the method is private or not shouldn't matter for the optimization, unless your configuration explicitly keeps public methods.